# Visually designing a Visual C++ Windowed Application

Tags: visual-studio-2005

If you want a dialog application, MSVC++ 2005 is OK, but when I create a SDI application I don't see any visual layout tools.
is this possible? And are there any better resource editing/mocking tools for MFC apps?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want your view to look like.  If it's a view that's similar to a dialog, with control layouts, etc, you would make it a CFormView, and then would use the same dialog editor to lay out your form.

If your view is something with just custom display of the data, then you would use whichever control makes the most sense for your use case.  If your data is list-like, you would want to have your view derive from CListView, and so forth.